# Ubuntu Xenial Standard Installation w Encryption: Dropped all partitions - how to restore LUKS

Tags: partitioning, restore, luks

I know, I only have myself to blame, but yesterday I mistakenly deleted all my partitions of my main drive - a standard ubuntu xenial install using LUKS and LVM, but everything with default options using the whole 1 TByte drive. No EFI etc.

Here you can see fdisk -l from **another** laptop with the same installation (it has a smaller drive though!):

```
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 624949247 623947778 297.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 624949247 623947776 297.5G 83 Linux
```

Gpart is running (10 hours plus now), I also let testdisk do a scan but was confused as to what to do in the end (it also found some old HP_Tools partition which was deleted a long time ago). Sorry I'm still a learner with Linux.

I see that I could be able to restore the two main partitions sda1 and sda2, but how do I have to proceed to get the LUKS container inside sda2 back and the LVM inside the LUKS, while not actually changing any data?

Am I correct that by just dropping the partitions, I did not loose yet any data?

Thanks for any help with detailed steps.

Answer (score 1):

Few... I managed to solve it and to get all my partitions back. Here in a nutshell what I did:

First, I took an Ubuntu live USB drive and booted into the live system. Then:

1. install **gddrescue** and use **ddrescue** to backup the whole drive bit by bit into a file on an external drive. This gives peace of mind when playing around: The original state can always be restored if necessary
2. Use **testdisk** to do a quick search. It did not get the crypt partition right, but the boot one, so I restored that one with testdisk.
3. Use
   "grep -a -b -P --only-matching 'LUKS\xba\xbe' /dev/sda"
   to search for the beginning of the LUKS crypt.
4. Use 
   "losetup -o result_from_grep -r -f /dev/sda" and 
   "hexdump -C -n 128 /dev/loop0"
   to verify if this is really the beginning of the LUKS crypt including the header. It should look something like: |LUKS....aes.....|
5. The grep returned the start in Bytes, calculate it in sectors
6. Use **parted** to create an Extended partition starting two sectors before the LUKS crypt, till -1s (End of Disk, as in my case, the whole rest of the disk was used)
7. Use parted to create a logical partition on the sector where the LUKS crypt starts until -3s (three sectors before the end - see my example fdisk -l in the question)
8. Open the crypt and follow the steps as outlined in link 2 to restore SWAP, root etc.
9. You can try to save your data at this point, but in my case I could just reboot and get the computer up and running normally again.

These three links helped me with the different steps, as well as man pages of the commands:

1) [parted: how to create the partitions exactly at the right positions](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/621/force-new-partition-start-at-certain-sector-number-parted#.WNEy9kehXCJ)

2) [Mount crypt and find all the logical volumes again](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266650)

I hope this helps others with similar problems.

Comment: In step 4, that should have been:
'losetup -o 1048576 -r -f /dev/sdb' 
where the number is the byte offset provided by grep.
See (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1643334&page=2) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your result :-) BTW; You can edit your answer instead of adding corrections in a comment :-)

Comment: Oops, true - but I was not allowed to share three links in one answers ;-)